# trouble with View or something in Android

Tags: android

I am currently in trouble with my project.

I am trying to separate functions into different classes instead of putting all in Activity class.

So I think I need to pass "view" from SettingsActivity to ConfigPresenter, from ConfigPresenter to ConfigEventHandler.

but I don not know why it doesn't work at all.

can anyone help me to know what the problem is?

Appreciate all the time and sorry that I only come stackoverflow to get information.

I hope I become a professional someday and help people here. :)

I make errors bold below.

---

```
SettingsActivity.java

 - configPresenter.optionClicked **(view)**

ConfigPresenter.java

 - eh.checkOption **(view)** 

ConfigEventHandler.java

 - AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder **(SettingsActivity.class)**
 - LayoutInflater inflater = SettingsActivity.class.**getLayoutInflater()**
 - TextView titleUrl = (TextView) **findViewById**(title);
 - TextView optionUrl = (TextView) **findViewById**(option);
```

---

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConfigPresenter.View {

    private ConfigPresenter configPresenter;
    private Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }

    public void optionClicked(View view) {
        configPresenter.optionClicked(view);
    }
}
```

**ConfigPresenter.java**

```
public class ConfigPresenter {
    private View view;
    private ConfigEventHandler eh;
    private ConfigFileHandler fh;

    public ConfigPresenter(ConfigPresenter.View view) {
        this.view = view;
        eh = new ConfigEventHandler();
        fh = new ConfigFileHandler();
    }

    public void optionClicked(View view) {
        eh.checkOption(view);
        Log.d("Config", "Presenter");
    }
}
```

**ConfigEventHandler.java**

```
public class ConfigEventHandler {

    public void checkOption(View view) {
        if ( view.getId() == R.id.layout_url ) {
            showDialog(R.id.title_url, R.id.option_url);
        } else if ( view.getId() == R.id.layout_port ) {
            showDialog(R.id.title_port, R.id.option_port);
        } else {
            showDialog(R.id.title_path, R.id.option_path);
        }
    }

    public void showDialog(int title, int option) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.class);

        LayoutInflater inflater = SettingsActivity.class.getLayoutInflater();
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

        builder.setView(content);

        TextView titleUrl = (TextView) findViewById(title);
        TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        TextView optionUrl = (TextView) findViewById(option);
        EditText dialogOption = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_option);
        dialogTitle.setText(titleUrl.getText());
        dialogOption.setText(optionUrl.getText());

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // ok
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // cancel
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your classes aren't logical, but a few fixes for your current setup.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setcontentview etc.
}

public void optionClicked(View view){
    ConfigPresenter.optionClicked(view,getLayoutInflater(),this);
}
}
```

ConfigPresenter

```
public class ConfigPresenter {

public static void optionClicked(View view, LayoutInflater inflater, Context context){
    ConfigEventHandler.checkOption(view,inflater,context);
}
}
```

ConfigEventHandler

```
public class ConfigEventHandler {

public static void checkOption(View view, LayoutInflater inflater, Context context){
    showDialog(inflater,context);
}

private static void showDialog(LayoutInflater inflater, Context context){
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_add_item,null);

    dialog.setContentView(content);
    dialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Opoo!! Actually I haven't tried yet because it's 8:30pm here  so I will try this tomorrow! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In SettingsActivity:

```
private ConfigPresenter configPresenter;
private Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
  // Initialize configPresenter:
  configPresenter = new ConfigPresenter(this)
}
```

And in the constructor method in ConfigPresenter, you can remove the weird ConfigPresenter.View like this:

```
public class ConfigPresenter {
  private ConfigEventHandler eh;
  private ConfigFileHandler fh;
  private Context context;

  public ConfigPresenter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    eh = new ConfigEventHandler(context);
    fh = new ConfigFileHandler();
  }
/* ... */
}
```

EDIT:The Context also needs to be passed down. Edited code above, and the edits below also needs to be added.

```
public class ConfigEventHandler {

  private Context context;

  // Constructor with Context
  public ConfigEventHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  /* ... */

public void showDialog(int title, int option) {
   // Passing the context to the Builder: 
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   /* ... */
}
```

However - this approach seems to only cause a lot of headache. Why do you want to split up your code in so many classes?

Comment: Thank you Marcus! I hope it works! Reason why I split up is for MVP Pattern maybe.. I'm newbie at company especially in android and my boss want me to follow mvp pattern